# How does a variable refer to the same variable in vba?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, variables

total beginner here. I have a hard time understanding the following code, or any code that operates the same variable.

For example:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 3
i = i + 1
Next i

MsgBox (i)

End Sub
```

Why does this return 5?

Comment: Code such as this should be burnt with fire. Just saying.

Comment: *I have a hard time understanding the following code* - don't worry, that's completely normal: this is exactly why incrementing a `For` loop counter inside the loop's body is a bad practice and should be avoided at all costs, as @DeanOC kind of hinted at. It's great that you're experimenting and trying to understand things, keep it up!

Answer (score 2):

You should note that typically it's bad practise to alter a `For` loop counter inside the loop.

Here's what's going on though:

As the loop runs, `Next i` adds one to the value of `i` (even though you already added one...)  - if the value of `i` is outside of the `For` bounds then the loop terminates.

So:

Iteration 1: `i` enters the loop as 1, is incremented to 2, then again to 3 by the `Next i`

Iteration 2: `i` enters the loop as 3, is incremented to 4, then again to 5 by the `Next i`

5 is outside of 1-3, so `i` ends up as 5

Comment: *"You should note that typically it's bad practise to alter a For loop counter inside the loop"* -- THIS!! Have an upvote! (++ for the rest of the answer as well =)

Answer (score 0):

Saying `i = i + 1` has the same effect that `Next i`.  You basically are adding 1 to i within the `for` statement and once again when you increment it.

```
For i = 1 to 3 'starts with i = 1
    i = i + 1 'adds 1 to i, i = 2 in the first loop
Next i  'adds 1 to i, i = 3 at the end of the first loop. Thee second loop starts
```

i starts the secons loop with a value of 3 and you add 1 to it when 
 `i = i + 1`  and once again when `Next i`

I hope this helps you understand it and sorry that my answer is a bit untidy, I'm answering from my mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your `For` loop re-written using a `While` loop:

```
i = 1
While i >= 1 And i <= 3
    i = i + 1
    i = i + 1
End While
```

Note that `Next i` is directly translated as `i = i + 1` - so now for each iteration of the loop you are effectively performing `i = i + 2`.

Since `i` is `1` at the start it matches the loop condition so we add `2` to `i`. It still matches the loop condition so we execute the loop again adding another `2`.

This means that `i` is `1 + 2 + 2` or `5`.

Comment: It'll run just once with the loop "condition" as `<= 3`, it will never reach 5.

Comment: @EEM - Why is that? After the first iteration the value of `i` is `3` so it would iterate a second time.